# TreeSet Comparator performing inconsistently

Tags: java

See the following 2 classes, `DTO` and `DTOWithOrdering`:

```
public class DTO  {
    private final String key;
    private final long recordVersionNumber;

    public DTO(String key) {
        this.key = key;
        this.recordVersionNumber = 0;
    }

    public DTO(String key, long recordVersionNumber) {
        this.key = key;
        this.recordVersionNumber = recordVersionNumber;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public long getRecordVersionNumber() {
        return recordVersionNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Key: " + this.key + " Record Version Number: " + this.recordVersionNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        DTO that = (DTO) o;

        return Objects.equal(this.key, that.key) &&
                Objects.equal(this.recordVersionNumber, that.recordVersionNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(key, recordVersionNumber);
    }

public class DTOWithOrdering extends DTO implements Comparable<DTOWithOrdering> {

    public DTOWithOrdering(String key, long recordVersionNumber) {
        super(key, recordVersionNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        DTOWithOrdering other = (DTOWithOrdering) o;

        if(this.getKey().equals(other.getKey())) {
            if(this.getRecordVersionNumber() == other.getRecordVersionNumber()) {
                return true;
            } else if(this.getRecordVersionNumber() <= other.getRecordVersionNumber()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DTOWithOrdering other) {
        if(this.getKey().equals(other.getKey())) {
            if(this.getRecordVersionNumber() == other.getRecordVersionNumber()) {
                return 0;
            } else if(this.getRecordVersionNumber() <= other.getRecordVersionNumber()) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

`DTOWIthOrdering` extends from `DTO` and overrides the `equals` and `compareTo` methods.

The problem arises with the following code snippet when I create a `TreeSet<DTOWIthOrdering>` and invoke contains on this

```
TreeSet<DTOWithOrdering> treeSet = new TreeSet<DTOWithOrdering>(keyAndVersionList);
    List<DTO> results = new ArrayList<DTO>();
    for (DTO diff : diffs) {
        if (treeSet.contains(new DTOWithOrdering(diff.getKey(), diff.getRecordVersionNumber())) == false) {
            results.add(diff);
        }
    }
```

When I run this within my program I can see that treeSet contains 2700+ entities, one of which has a key of 0b3ae620-bbcf-347d-a9b4-87e6fd765cd7 and recordVersionNumber of 4

However, one of the diff entities contains the same key with a recordVersionNumber of 0.

When the code invokes the contains method, the set returns a value of false.

Strangely, for other examples, where the keys are equal and the record version number is greater in the TreeSet it returns true!

Is there something wrong here with my logic?

Comment: Your `compareTo` in `DTOWithOrdering` method looks strange because it never returns `1`. Are you sure it does exactly what you want?

Comment: As a side note, this is a great example of a case where unit tests on `compareTo` would probably identify and diagnose the bug.

Comment: Must it return 1? I admit it's an inefficient comparator in that it will effectively be a list but does that explain why contains() is returning false?

Comment: I *think*, the logic is reversed, in your `equals()`, other comes from `diff` (`contains` use `equals`).

Comment: When a comparator returns `0` it means that the two objects are *equal* which will be respected by sorted collections like `TreeSet`. And you say `if(this.getRecordVersionNumber() <= other.getRecordVersionNumber()) { return 0; }` … just think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quote from JavaDoc for `Comparable` interface:

> int compareTo(T o)
>
> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a
>   negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object. The implementor
>   must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and
>   y. (This implies that x.compareTo(y) must throw an exception if
>   y.compareTo(x) throws an exception.)

If you return `-1` but never return `1`, the property
   `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))` cannot hold true. So your implementation of this method does not conform to the specification and `TreeSet` can work improperly.